# how can i plot profit loss graph in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph

I have income, expense and user controller i want to plot graph of profit loss of current user i have following code in user model.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :incomes
  has_many :expenses

  def total_expense
    expenses.pluck(:amount).sum
  end

  def total_incomes
    incomes.pluck(:amount).sum
  end

  def profit_loss
    total_incomes - total_expense
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

but `proft_loss` is not saved in database.

Comment: Which version of Rails you are using? Are you using webpack?

Comment: `profit_loss` is just a method in the model. Where do you save it to DB?

Comment: I am using rails version 5.2, No profit loss method is not save in the db.  Its just a method in model

Comment: @AmitPatel i am using rails version Rails 5.2.4.2
and iam not using the webpack